# integrate mailchimp api in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, api, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3

I am integrating mailchimp api in asp.net.

web.config:

```
<add key="APIKey" value="XXXX9dsfij4yZXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" />
```

in code

```
using mailchimp;

IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager();
```

when I see what's in 'manager' object, it's null.

how do i get api key from web.config file?

Comment: I think you missed API Key to initialize, it should be `IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(*API KEY*);`

Comment: how can I access api key from code when i put key in web.config file?

Comment: You can read API key via `ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];` you need to add `System.Configuration` reference to use `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: Or you can change config name : `<add key="APIKey" value="XXXX9dsfij4yZXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" />` to `<add key="MailChimpApiKey" value="XXXX9dsfij4yZXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to:
https://github.com/brandonseydel/MailChimp.Net/blob/master/README.md You have two options here.

First, you can manually read API key from config:

```
using mailchimp;
using System.Configuration;

//Read API key from config
var apiKey= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APIKey"];

IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager(apiKey);
```

Second option is that you can change read key to `MailChimpApiKey`, so change

```
<add key="APIKey" value="XXXX9dsfij4yZXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" />
```

to

```
<add key="MailChimpApiKey" value="XXXX9dsfij4yZXXXXXXXXXX-XXXX" />
```

In that case you don't need to pass API key:

```
using mailchimp;

IMailChimpManager manager = new MailChimpManager();
```